# Question on self adjoint properties

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators

[image]

I have the follwing question and have managed to do it all apart from the last 3 parts of c) showing the various statements. Cant figure out where to start! Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Just to check: you do realize that the $S$ in question c is the same $S$ introduced in question b? I.e., that $Q = S^2$ is a positive definite self-adjoint transformation.

Comment: Yes, I used that to answer the first part of c), but for the next 3 parts i think I'm just having trouble coming up with the scalars and vectors

Comment: Okay - I just wanted to check because I've run into several posts where the problem was the asker simply didn't realize a series of questions were related.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $S^{-1}PS^{-1}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $$PS^{-1}v = \lambda Sv$$
Now let $e = S^{-1}v$.

Comment: Okay, that makes alot more sense, I think I can try work my way through thank you! One quick question, how do we know that $S^{-1}PS^{-1}$ has n distinct eigenvectors?

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't had much time. I was just showing where the $e$s and $\lambda$s come from. Whether they can be chosen to satisfy the conditions, you will have to investigate yourself. You might see if you can prove that $S^{-1}PS^{-1}$ is normal - or if it is possible to find an example that isn't normal. However, if you can demonstrate that $S^{-1}PS^{-1}$ has a complete set of eigenvectors, the remaining conditions should follow readily.